# Need help using core data to hold my parsed data

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data

I am at a real loss.. For the past two weeks I have been working on fine tuning the way data is parsed, displayed and held in my app.

I have two view controllers, the first has four tables that when selected load a uitableview full of data that is parsed from an xml file. each xml file is different but have key fields that relate to each other. I need to speed up the way I display this data in the uitableview as when I do my second search when I check my ManufactureID against every single modle avalible to all manufactures.. it take a considrible amount of time to load.

I would like to do this behind the scenes before the view is even about to load and I have heard the best way to achieve this will be to use core data.. but I am not sure how to get this to work with the way I am doing things now.

If you have any examples, suggestions or anything that might help me I could seriously use someones input right about now as I am just abit stuck. For instance how do I get the data that are in my .xml files into the coredata? how to I create the relation ship ID's? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, is there any reason to keep the information in XML files? Everything will be a lot easier (and faster!) if you just move it all to a CoreData datastore from the start instead of parsing/preloading everything to an in-memory store at launch (or whatever).

As to how to model your relationships, you could always set your CoreData model to exactly match your XML data. So, say, one Entity per file and one Attribute per record in said file. There's no reason you *have* to use CoreData Relationships to model the relationships in your XML. If you have IDs in the files already, just make an Attribute called `xmlId` or something and fetch based on that just like you were doing a SQL query. You'd miss out on a lot of automatic ORM-ness of CoreData, but if you've been dealing with XML this whole time, I doubt you'll notice.

If you really want to set up the relationships between your CoreData-managed objects, you'll have to somehow match up objects by their IDs in the XML either by importing the IDs into CoreData and then doing the math, or by somehow taking care of this when you parse. Hard to give any specific advice here without knowing more about how your data are modeled.

There's some sample code that does half of what you want (it reads XML into a in-memory CoreData store, but doesn't model any relationships). Check out TopSongs (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TopSongs)

Comment: well there will be points in which the xml dose change (several times per year). there is a field in the xml I can check to see if the database has been updated. but yes I have been thinking more and more about doing an initial query on the database to get all of the xml in one go.

Comment: I know nothing of your app, so grain of salt ;-) but you're treating the XML as your data and CoreData as an intermediary format. I've always found it's better to treat CoreData as the data and use XML as an intermediary format (for pulling from a web service, distributing changes, etc)

Comment: Yea I think thats the realization I'm starting to have. Thanks for your reply... Im going to continue reading examples etc and give it a crack. I think the thing holding me back currently is the fact I have already started heading down the track of xml only no core data.. and I have to go back on little bit of code... but just scared of making the change.